# Custom Roweditor

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Saludos. Tengo el siguiente problema. Dado la siguiente vista:

**cliente.xhtml**

```
    <p:fieldset>
        <p:fieldset legend="Informacion Personal del Cliente">
            <h:panelGrid id="panelCliente"
                         columns="6" 
                         columnClasses="headerColPanelGrid, 
                         valueColPanelGrid, 
                         errorColPanelGrid,
                         headerColPanelGrid, 
                         valueColPanelGrid, 
                         errorColPanelGrid"
                         >                 
                <p:outputLabel for="txtClienteNombres" 
                               value="Nombres *"/>
                <p:inputText id="txtClienteNombres" 
                             required="false" 
                             class="textBoxWidth100"
                             value="#{clienteController.cliente.nombres}"
                             placeholder="Ingrese Nombres"
                             immediate="false"
                             validator="clienteValidator"
                             converter="soloTextoV1Converter"
                             >
                </p:inputText>
                <p:message for="txtClienteNombres"/>

                <p:outputLabel for="txtClienteApellidos" 
                               value="Apellidos *"/>
                <p:inputText id="txtClienteApellidos" 
                             required="false" 
                             class="textBoxWidth100" 
                             value="#{clienteController.cliente.apellidos}"
                             placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos"
                             immediate="false"
                             validator="clienteValidator"
                             converter="soloTextoV1Converter"
                             >
                </p:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>    

        <p:commandButton id="cmdClienteReservar"
                         actionListener="#{clienteController.saveTmp()}" 
                         value="Reservar"
                         update="@parent"
                         immediate="false"
                         >
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton  id="cmdClienteCrear"
                          actionListener="#{clienteController.createCliente()}" 
                          value="Crear" 
                          update="@parent"
                          rendered="#{clienteController.cliente.id lt 0}"
                          onstart="PF('BUI').show()" 
                          oncomplete="PF('BUI').hide()"
                          >     
            <f:param name="paramValidate" value="true" />
            <f:param name="paramTipoIdent" value="#{clienteController.cliente.tipoIdentificacion}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton  id="cmdClienteEditar"
                          actionListener="#{clienteController.editCliente()}" 
                          value="Editar" 
                          update="@parent"
                          rendered="#{clienteController.cliente.id gt 0}"
                          onstart="PF('BUI').show()" 
                          oncomplete="PF('BUI').hide()"
                          >
            <f:param name="paramValidate" value="true" />
            <f:param name="paramTipoIdent" value="#{clienteController.cliente.tipoIdentificacion}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:fieldset>
```

La misma contiene un validador que recibe un parámetro **paramValidate**, el mismo que solo validara cuando sean los eventos Crear o Editar para posteriormente guardarlos en la base de datos. Y en el evento Reservar me permite guardar temporalmente los datos en un arreglo sin necesidad de validar.

**clienteValidator**

```
    @FacesValidator
    public class ClienteValidator implements Validator {

        @Override
        public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
            if (!continueValidacion()) {
                return;
            }

            FacesMessage fm;
            String comp = (String) component.getId();
            String valor;
            Date valorFecha;

            ...........

        }

        protected boolean continueValidacion() {
            String skipValidator = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                    getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("paramValidate");
            return (skipValidator != null && skipValidator.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
        }

    }
```

Ahora necesito plantear el mismo esquema pero para un datatable, pero el problema es que el componentes **roweditor** no permite pasar parametros.

**contactos.xhtml**

```
                <c:if test="#{clienteController.cliente.id > 0}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <p:outputPanel style="text-align: right;">
                            <p:commandButton value="Nuevo Contacto" 
                                             actionListener="#{clienteController.onRowAddContacto}"
                                             update="dataTableContacto" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                        <p:outputPanel style="text-align: right;">
                            <p:commandButton value="Editar Contacto" 
                                             actionListener="#{clienteController.onRowEditContacto}"
                                             update="dataTableContacto" />
                        </p:outputPanel>
                    </f:facet>
                </c:if>                    

                <p:column id="colContactoId" 
                          headerText="Id"
                          visible="true">     
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{contacto.id}"
                                          />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="txtContactoId" 
                                         readonly="true"
                                         value="#{contacto.id}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="colContactoTipo" 
                          headerText="Tipo Contacto">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{globalController.getEtiquetaContactoTipos(contacto.tipoContacto)}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:selectOneMenu id="cmbContactoTipo" 
                                             required="false"
                                             value="#{contacto.tipoContacto}"
                                             style="width: 90%"
                                             placeholder="Tipo de Contacto"
                                             immediate="false"
                                             validator="contactoValidator"
                                             >
                                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" 
                                              itemLabel="--Seleccione--" />
                                <f:selectItems value="#{globalController.comboContactoTipos}" />
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="colContactoValor" 
                          headerText="Descripcion">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{contacto.valor}"
                                          class="textBoxWidth100"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="txtContactoValor" 
                                         value="#{contacto.valor}" 
                                         class="textBoxWidth100"
                                         placeholder="Descripcion del Contacto"
                                         immediate="false"
                                         validator="contactoValidator"
                                         converter="soloTextoNumeroV3Converter"
                                         >
                            </p:inputText>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="colContactoEstado" 
                          headerText="Estado">
                    <h:outputText value="#{globalController.getEtiquetaGeneralEstados(contactos.estado)}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="colContactoFecCreacion" 
                          headerText="Fec. Creacion" >
                    <h:outputText value="#{contacto.fechaCreacion}">
                        <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
                    </h:outputText>
                </p:column>

                <p:column id="colContactoEditor"
                            style="width: 50px"
                          headerText="Editar">
                    <p:rowEditor id="cmdContactoEditar">
                        <f:param name="paramValidate" value="true" />
                    </p:rowEditor>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

**validateContacto**

```
    @FacesValidator
    public class ContactoValidator implements Validator {

        @Override
        public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
            if (!continueValidacion()) {
                return;
            }

            FacesMessage fm;
            String comp = (String) component.getId();
            String valor;

            .....
        }

        protected boolean continueValidacion() {
            String skipValidator = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().
                    getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("paramValidate");
            return (skipValidator != null && skipValidator.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
        }

    }
```

La pregunta es. Como podria pasar el parametro **paramValidate** dentro del **roweditor**, o como podriar simular la funcionalidad del edit/update/cancel del datatable con botones para de esta manera enviar dicho parametro

Gracias